# Services and Scheduled Tasks assigned to a user account

Tags: passwords, scheduled-tasks, group-policy, password-policy

In Windows Server 2008 R2

Lets assume user acct: User1

Password for User: 1234

I have assigned an automatic service to run based on User1's credentials for startup of service. I have also created a scheduled task that runs daily called ST1 that is assigned to run under the same users "User1" logon credentials.

Everything works fine if the password is set to not expire on the user and the password is not changed.

However I need the password to be changed for the user based on group policy every lets say 90 days.

This password change does not update the service or the scheduled task of the change of the users password and hence those services and scheduled tasks no longer function and the end-user has to manually go to each location where such a logon credential was assigned and change the password.

Is there some way to automate this password change to update all locations where the users logon is being utilized since the password change is being initiated through Windows User Account?

Is there a way to get a list of all services and scheduled tasks that are assigned to a specific user? At least that would remind me which locations I would need to update manually.